# Google Cloud run, Django and sqlite

Tags: django, docker, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-run

I'm developing small single user applications in Django. Currently I do so with Heroku, which works just fine. I would like to deploy the application on Google Cloud run to have in the future a bit more flexibility.

In order to keep the overhead as small as possible I was considering using Sqlite. To keep persistency all I would need is a persistent volume, which could be achived via Google Cloud storage that is mounted into the docker container via gcsfuse. But here is the issue. I can't find a small Image with python and gcsfuse. I'm not a docker pro. Just getting started...

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: checkout this project ... I'm not the author, but this https://hub.docker.com/r/ekino/gcsfuse would be a good start... Maybe install python into it... or find a python image and install gcsfuse into it

Comment: AFAIK, gVisor, the default Cloud RUn sandbox will reject your GCS fuse mount. Have a try, I'm interested in the result!

Comment: I have tried for a loooong time, thats why I ended here ;-) I will probably spin up a small SQL instance... seems like at least for the moment there is no such solution possible

Answer (score 0):

Google itself provides a HowTo Deploy a (simple) Django app to Google Cloud Run:

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-run-django/

I myself as a Google Cloud rookie followed it step by step and it worked without any problems. By the way, I found that via the [episode of the podcast Django Chat "Advanced Deployment" with Katie McLaughlin](https://djangochat.com/episodes/advanced-deployment-katie-mclaughlin).

The HowTo use a Cloud SQL instance instead of Sqlite, but this seems to be a good choice:

> „Generally speaking SQLite is not a good database choice for
> professional websites. So while it is fine to use SQLite locally while
> prototyping an idea, it is rare to actually use SQLite as the database
> on a production project.“
>
> [William S. Vincent. „Django for Professionals, Chapter 2](https://djangoforprofessionals.com/docker/)

Letting this apart it shouldn't be so hard to skip the Cloud SQL step and keep SQLite.

Comment: Ignore that old notion that sqlite isn't for "production" web applications. "Generally speaking, any site that gets fewer than 100K hits/day should work fine with SQLite."  https://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html. For more discussion check out: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=33975635